# In Azure DevOps, dashboard for monitoring target dates

Tags: azure-devops

I want to create a dashboard that can show me a chart that can categorize work items into the following:

- Category 1: Work items with Target Dates lapsed
- Category 2: Work items with Target Dates due in 5 days
- Category 3: Work items with Target Dates due in more than 5 days

I need to show all three categories in one chart. Is there a way I can achieve that? It doesn't have to be a chart. I could create 3 separate queries (1 one for each category) but I don't think there's a widget that can use 3 queries at the same time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to show all three categories in one chart. Is there a way I can
> achieve that?

I am afraid this is impossible to achieve in azure devops. There is currently no such widget that can display three queries. In addition, three queries cannot be displayed in one chart. One query corresponds to one chart.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

Comment: Thanks Hugh. I'm aware that there are no widgets that can use three queries at a time. Just wondering if anyone can suggest a workaround. Right now, I'm thinking of creating one query for each category and assign each to a work item tile widget. It's quite unglamorous to be honest. But it's the best I can think of right now. Hoping someone can suggest a better way.

Comment: `creating one query for each category and assign each to a work item tile widget.` So far, you can only do this. You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) site